# How to test ajax based site?

Tags: java, javascript, unit-testing, selenium

I want to create automated tests for my site which is totall ajax based. The is developed using Spring MVC/Java. I have some knowledge of Selenium and I have also created some tests using Selnium.

The problem here is that as site is purely ajax based so its very difficult to track/test each and everything from backend java code via Selenium.

How can I make life easier for such project?
Can I create my tests using javascript and run via Selenium from backend?

Some Problems
-- a lot of popups loading via ajax calls, I need to click buttons on popup... err: Cannot click hidden buttons
-- A lot of tables loading page wise data internally via ajax calls... traversing to next pages is very difficult to manage from Java's selenium code.

Comment: This is very vague...can you explain when you had a problem in testing something that was Ajax'y?

Comment: Shouldn't you have backend tests that do not rely on the front end? What you seem like you are doing is "User Acceptance" testing where you push *X* button and expect *Y* to happen.

Comment: @Arran: Check some problems... I updated question

Comment: @epascarello: yes u r right it should b independent... I have to write test to verify end to end web functionality from browser point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium provides for several languages webdrivers to execute those test from backend. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

alternatively:

Check out http://qunitjs.com/ my favorite javascript testing framework, i d advice 2 you